# Newline character not working from txt file in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, newline

I am parsing a simple `.txt` file in Swift and have encountered a weird issue.

The text file is as follows:

```
This is a test \nThis should be on a new line
```

Here is my code:

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "txt")
let example = try? String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: .utf8)
let example1 = "This is a test. \nThis should be on a new line."
```

`example` prints like this:

```
This is a test \nThis should be on a new line
```

While `example1` prints like this:

```
This is a test 
This should be on a new line
```

Why is the new line character not detected when reading from a text file?

Answer (score 3):

What you see in the file contents is not the EOL character, which is not visible with the naked eye, but two characters: "\", and "n". If the file would've indeed have and EOL, it would've look the same as the output if the string you declared and printed.

"\n" is an escape sequence that allows you to programatically add line endings in custom strings. The compiler translates the "\n" combination into the character with code 10 (EOL for *nix platforms). This is what happens in your code, and this is why when printed, the string has an EOL.

Comment: Oh, now it makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @BalázsVincze To be precise, the actual content of the text file is `This is a test \\nThis should be on a new line` with a double backslash, escaping the backslash and rendering a regular `\n` when you open it to view the content.

Comment: @kevin you might confuse people with "the actual content" phrasing. They might think the two backslashes are part of the bytes that made up the file contents.

Comment: That comment is just wrong. There's nothing escaped in the file.

Answer (score 0):

The text file is read with the backslash being **escaped**. If you want to replace all occurrences of \n with a new line, use `replacingOccurrences(of:with:)`:

```
let exampleWithNewlines = example.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\n", with: "\n")
```